# Is using input to display readonly data semantically correct?

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I have a form that contains a particular mat-select that when the user selects an option, some data are displayed just to let the user confirm if the option selected is the right one. As I'm using material components for input's, I'm using readonly input's in another div to display the data for the user, so I get a consistent look and feel. But I wonder if this is semantically correct.

User selects a person here:

[image]

Data is shown here:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is personal, but I will share my thoughts on this issue.
I think this is OK especially if it helps you to keep the design consistent.
But you must make those inputs **disabled** to let the user know this is read-only data.